# pdflatex raise error when \paragraph inside quote environment

Tags: quoting, sections-paragraphs

Why I get a error when there is a `\paragraph{}` (or `\subparagraph{}`) inside a `quote` environment?

For the example below

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\paragraph{My header}

Some text.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

I got

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
$ pdflatex bug-sample.tex
...
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \end{quote}
```

Comment: I can put `\section` inside `quote` environment. Why not `\paragraph`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an answer but a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
  \mbox{}%
  \paragraph{My heading} starts something.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: paragraph headings are usually run in; section titles are usually not.  `\leavevmode` might also work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I had got as far as the run in bit. What I'm not able to figure out is why that matters. So I think the workaround works because `\mbox{}` basically counts as something fed to `\item` in the trivial list environment. But why do non-run in headers satisfy the environment without that while run in headers do not?

Comment: non-run-in headers "leave vmode" when they start a new line after the header.  (that sounds circular.)  yes, it does have to do with feeding something to the `\item`. (thinking of everything as a list -- as done with `quote`, theorems, etc., etc. -- is not how i would have parsed the structures, but i didn't design latex.  i've designed a number of styles based on plain tex, and i don't think there's a single list in the lot.  but latex got the critical mass first.)

Comment: re lists and plain tex, i lied.  indexes are based on list structures.  and actual lists.  but not quotes, or tables of contents (those are structured paragraphs), and certainly not theorems or proofs.  it's just historical fact.